# I want to generate random numbers then do the addition operation on them

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am 9 year old kid trying to automate the random numbers maths toward my abacus.

I want to generate values randomly and store them in memory for later ,when i press to check for addition. then it should give the addition value of all the random numbers.

so far I have this code

```
# my abacus training app

import random
import time

print ('hey what\'s your name')
name = input()

print("well today i am goingto ask abacus questions ")

print ("choose a level")
levelOne = print ("level 1")
print (levelOne)

choice = input()

if choice.endswith("1") :
    print("let's start")
    noone = random.randint(1,10)
    print (noone)
    time.sleep(5)
    notwo = random.randint(1,10)
    print (notwo)
    time.sleep(5)
    nothree = random.randint(1,10)
    print (nothree)
    time.sleep(5)
    nofour = random.randint(1,10)
    print (nofour)
    time.sleep(5)
    nofive = random.randint(1,10)
    print (nofive)
    time.sleep(5)
```

=======I am posting Final Answer for above question, this was my final code, Thanks to Srig  and Hamed Temsah for the inputs=== thanks to everyone who supported me.

```html
# my abacus training app

import random
import time

print ('hey what\'s your name')
name = input()

print("well today i am goingto ask abacus questions ")

print ("choose a level")



choice = input("choose a level : ")

if choice.endswith("1") :
    print("let's start")
    noone = random.randint(1,10)
    print (noone)
    time.sleep(10)
    notwo = random.randint(1,10)
    print (notwo)
    time.sleep(10)
    nothree = random.randint(1,10)
    print (nothree)
    time.sleep(10)
    nofour = random.randint(1,10)
    print (nofour)
    time.sleep(10)
    nofive = random.randint(1,10)
    print (nofive)
    time.sleep(10)
    print ("click enter to check your ans")
    input ()
    print(noone+notwo+nothree+nofour+nofive)
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving or problem you are facing?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line? `levelOne = print ("level 1")`

Comment: and where is PyGame in your problem ? why did you set tag 'pygame'?

Comment: I wanted to use that line for printing level 1 and storing it

Comment: @PranayKumar Doing that will not store the value.

Comment: my dad set up the PyGame  tag

Comment: I wanted to continue after my code this

Comment: calc = sum(int (noone, notwo))
    calc2 = sum(int (nothree, nofour))
    calc3 = sum(int (calc, calc2, nofive))
    print ("click enter to check your ans")

    input ()
    print (calc3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great job 9 year old kid, you did a great job!
If I understood your question clearly, you want to ask the user to input another character after generation of these 5 random numbers. If it had the character '+' , then you should print summation of all these random numbers, you can re-use your own code to achieve this like:

```
operand = input()
if operand.endswith("+") :
    print(noone+notwo+nothree+nofour+nofive)
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me and as my dad always says I am not alone... Thanks all I will be posting full code below

Answer (score 2):

You could do without `levelOne = print ("level 1")` and just do `print("level 1")` because `print()` returns `None`. To confirm this, try `levelOne == None`.

After the `if-statement`, you need to add all the numbers and `print` the sum.

Otherwise, your code is working as is. You may want to insert a prompt argument into `input()`, like so:

```
choice = input('Choose a level: ')
```

Hope that helps.